# How does have_posts() in Wordpress show only one post

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress is not my specialty and I'm helping a friend fix his site. On the home page of the website the following loop shows content based on that parameter passed. I'm trying to do the same and show different content based on the parameter but so far I have not been able to. My first confusion is that how does the loop only shows one post while there are other posts available and then how can I achieve the same if I pass in different parameters.

```
<?php if( empty($_GET)): ?>
   <div>Some content here...</div>
<?php elseif ($_GET['v'] === 'menu'): ?>

<?php

if (have_posts()) :
   while (have_posts()) :
      the_post();
      the_content();
   endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: I imagine they use the function to set a global variable, then they return true or false based on the pointer location in an internal array of posts...  Basically it's like calling next but instead of then calling current you call the_post.  It's a poor design pattern because as you can see, you don't know how it works.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I removed the if else condition check for $_GET and left the while loop in there and it shows that one menu post. Does this work like it shows only the last or first post in the database? I'm looking into it but there are sooo many posts in the database that came with the theme, more than 1 is active and published so not sure why always this one post shows. I'm thinking it is some dirty hack they pulled. i could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $arr = array("post 1\n","post 2\n","post 3\n","post 4\n");

    public function next(){
        return next($this->arr);
    }

    public function current(){
        return current($this->arr);
    }

}

global $MyClass;
$MyClass = new MyClass;


function have_posts(){
    global $MyClass;
    global $post;
    $post = $MyClass->current();

    $MyClass->next();

    return (bool)$post;
}

function the_post(){
    global $post;
    echo $post;
}


while(have_posts()){
    the_post();
}
```

Output

```
post 1
post 2
post 3
post 4
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ba9bb7593ba4e2340963d41257c8f5047b89391)

Comment: Hmm so you are saying there is probably already  a function of this sort in the code? You are right in saying that it is a bad design because I already know that that my friend hired someone that did a quick dirty job.
Not sure if my question was clear enough but i don't need all posts. The show different post with the template based on the parameter.They are sending v=menu and menu content shows up, same way I want to show e.g for contact v=contact and then show the contact post. So far home page is default content and then menu content.